# SQL order by - How to list seniority based on hire date

Tags: sql

[Screenshot from the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVkWn.png)
I am working on a practice test and cannot figure out why my answer was wrong.

The task was to order employees by seniority with the most senior employee first. 
It seems to me that seniority is higher when the hiredate is lower. The longer ago someone was hired, the more seniority they have. Therefore, I believe the correct answer should be #3 - order by hiredate (in ascending order). Also, in #2 the comment is that it would be correct but for the double quotes. But it would order by seniority in ascending order (less seniority first) which is incorrect.

What am I missing?
Thank you all!

Comment: I would say the test is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I made a table in SQL server with some dummy date inside and entered the following query:

`select *, Date1 seniority from Table_1  order by date1 desc`

I got this result:

`1  LastName    Smith           2012-05-05 00:00:00.000 2012-05-05 00:00:00.000
1   MiddleName  S               2012-04-04 00:00:00.000 2012-04-04 00:00:00.000
1   FirstName   Joe             2012-03-03 00:00:00.000 2012-03-03 00:00:00.000
1   Date        12/12/2009      2011-06-06 00:00:00.000 2011-06-06 00:00:00.000
2   MiddleName  Smith           2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 2011-05-05 00:00:00.000
2   FirstName   Sam             2011-04-04 00:00:00.000 2011-04-04 00:00:00.000`

From what I can tell, it looks like the test is wrong about both sort order and the need for quotes.  My only guess is that your test is referring to some other ANSI-compliant version of SQL.  I'm not going to buy a copy of the ANSI specification to check, though.

Answer (score 2):

Using `DESC` in the order by clause to sort dates works as you described it; the dates will be order from most recent to least recent.

See example 3 from [this Oracle article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-may/o32sql-1541432.html) demonstrating `ORDER BY` hire_date `DESC`.

In this case you are correct that you should `ORDER BY` hiredate `ASC` (the default).

The fact that the explanation statements are in the wrong order also suggests you may have identified an errata in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are rigth, the seniority is lower when the hiredate is lower. But in the answers they give you, they are substracting the todays date minus the hiredate, so the result you get is the number of years each employee has been hired (in years because you divide by 365).
So the greatest is the number, the more years he has been in the company. That´s the reason you need to order by in desc mode

Comment: You are still ordering by the hiredate, not the years. No matter what calculation you perform, the employee with the longest tenure would be listed first in ascending order. This is such an awful test question.

Comment: Yes, but in **mysql** when you order dates, the first date it´s the date closest to today, so if you need to set first the oldest one (the one is dar away from today) you need to do it DESC ('When working on date types, the latest date is shown on top of the list.')